# ubuntu запуск bash скрипта

Tags: ubuntu, bash

Как в *Ubuntu* сделать так, чтобы *bash*-скрипт запускался сразу после запуска *ОС*?

У меня есть скрипт `tochpad_settings.sh`, и для того, чтобы его запустить, каждый раз при перезапуске *ОС* приходится запускать его посредством команды в терминале `sh touchpad_settings.sh`.

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO  
# Provides:          touchpad_settings.sh  
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog  
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog  
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5  
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6  
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time  
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.  
### END INIT INFO  
synclient TapButton2=2  
synclient TapButton3=3  
synclient VertEdgeScroll=1  
synclient CircularScrolling=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

перечисленные вами команды служат для конфигурирования «тачпадов» *synaptics* и должны выполняться от имени пользователя после открытия им *x*-сессии.

логичнее оформить их в виде скрипта:

```
#!/bin/sh
synclient TapButton2=2  
synclient TapButton3=3  
synclient VertEdgeScroll=1  
synclient CircularScrolling=1
```

и сохранить файл где-нибудь внутри домашнего каталога под произвольным именем, например, `~/run.synclient`, не забыв, конечно, установить на файле биты исполняемости:

```
$ chmod +x ~/run.synclient
```

вот [здесь](https://askubuntu.com/a/48327/416190) «в картинках» рассказано, как добавить выполнение какой-нибудь программы при старте *x*-сессии средствами *desktop environment*. в качестве программы можете указать вот этот самый скрипт.

альтернативный путь — добавить строчку с вызовом вашего скрипта в файл, интерпретируемый при старте *x*-сессии: `~/.xsessionrc`:

```
$ echo ~/run.synclient >> ~/.xsessionrc
```

Comment: я верно понимаю, что этот файл интерпретируется ещё до логина?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я бы сказал — «в процессе». т.е. после ввода логина и пароля в *dm-е* (*display manager*), но до завершения загрузки *de/wm* (*desktop environment /window manager*).

Comment: о, спасибо, буду знать.