# Запуск GUI приложения на Ubuntu посредством локально-установленного Apache2.4

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache

Запуск производится посредством метода shell_exec() в логах apache всегда `cannot connect to X server` 
Все что нагуглил не помогло (Xvfb). Куда копать дальше не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Решил
$command = 'export DISPLAY=:0; ./App;';
exec($command)

Comment: у вас процессы apache работают от имени того же пользователя, который запускает x-сессию?

Comment: Да, они работают от одного имени. Дело в том что это приложение предназначено исключительно для локального использования и это не сыграет большой роли.

Answer (score 1):

предоставление доступа к *x-сессии*, запущенной на той же машине другим пользователем, можно реализовать разными способами, и многие из них ведут к «дырам» в безопасности.

---

наименее «болезненный» (как с точки зрения простоты реализации, так и с точки зрения безопасности), пожалуй, такой:

от имени пользователя, запустившего *x-сессию* (и в «рамках» этой сессии, т.е., из *shell-a*, работающего в, например, x-эмуляторе терминала — *(u)xterm*, *gnome-terminal*, *konsole* и т.п.), выполните команду:

```
$ xhost +si:localuser:имя
localuser:имя being added to access control list
```

после этого локальный пользователь с именем «имя» сможет запускать x-клиентов (т.н. «графические программы»), которые смогут взаимодействовать с вашей x-сессией.

---

пример вывода программы `xhost` без параметров **до** выполнения упомянутой выше команды («я» — это имя пользователя, запустившего *x-сессию*):

```
$ xhost
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
SI:localuser:я
```

и **после**:

```
$ xhost
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
SI:localuser:имя
SI:localuser:я
```

отозвать обратно предоставленный доступ можно в любой момент, выполнив аналогичную команду, в которой `+` заменён на `-`:

```
$ xhost -si:localuser:имя
localuser:имя being removed from access control list
```

---

внесённые изменения будут действительны до следующего перезапуска *x-сессии*.

---

для того, чтобы выдавать полномочия каждый раз при запуске *x-сессии* автоматически, можно добавить упомянутую команду, например, [в `~/.xsessionrc`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/456116/178576)